# Push array into an array using array_push

Tags: php, arrays

I have four elements of data stored in variables.

I wish to create a multi-dimensional array.

Firstly, I wish the ID to be the main key for the array. And within the ID key, I wish to store `description`, `image_med` and `image_full`

I have started by initialising an array and pushing the ID:

```
$image_id = $image['id'];
$this_image = array();
array_push($this_image, $image_id);
```

The result is:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  int(2161)
}
```

Now I wish to push three more elements into this ID array. I'd like to create something like the following:

```
array(1) {
      ['ID']=>
      int(2161)
      array(3){
       ['description'] => string(Description goes here),
       ['medium'] => string(http://www.blah.com/12345),
       ['full'] => string(http://www.blah.com/67890)
      }
    }
```

So first of all the parent key is called `ID` not just `[0]`

And secondly that the following three variables are added with their keys:

`description` (`$image_desc` is the variable)

`medium` (`$image_med` is the variable)

`full` (`$image_full` is the variable)

How would I do this?

Comment: Your desired output is not valid. What does `array['ID']` point to? `2126` or the array of description, medium and full? Also what if you add multiple fields, they should all have the key `ID`? However, if you use the ID as an key, aka `2126 => array(..` this will become a very basic task

Comment: Hi there, sorry you are correct I have got it a little wrong. The ID could be the key, that would be great.

Comment: array_push($this_image, array("id" => $image_id));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $id be the id of the image:

```
$array=array();

//then you can use this code in a loop:
$array[$id]=array(
'description'=>$image_desc,
'medium'=>$image_med,
'full'=> image_full
);
```

There is no need to use array_push function, actually array_push has a little worse performance because of function call's overhead (this is an advanced topic, anyway)

Comment: If I then wanted to go and put the whole of `$array` inside another array (where the ID field is the identifier) but I don't want to overwrite it, how would I do that? If you imagine that I have this data for just one ID and now I want to store it in a big array of lots of IDs

Answer (score 0):

is that what you are looking for ?

```
$images = array(); // an array of all images
$image_id = $image['id'];

$images[$image_id] = array(
    'ID' => $image_id, // optional, would be repeating id you already have
    'description' => "Blabla",
    'medium' => "Blabla",
    'full' => "Blabla",
);
```

You would do that automatically in a loop I suppose thought... And if you dont need the ID as "key", what about:

```
$images = array();
$image1 = array(
        'ID' => $image_id,
        'description' => "Blabla",
        'medium' => "Blabla",
        'full' => "Blabla",
    );

array_push($images, $image1);
```

Not sure what you are looking to achieve though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. What you probably need could be something like this:

```
// Create a list (of images)
$listImages = array();


// Information about an image (it can be constructed as displayed here,
// retrieved from a database or from other source)
$image = array(
    'id' => 123,
    'description' => 'Nice kitty',
    'medium' => 'http://www.blah.com/12345',
    'full' => 'http://www.blah.com/67890',
);

// Extract the ID of the image into a variable (this is for code clarity)
$imageId = $image['id'];

// Store the image in the list, indexed by image ID
$listImages[$imageId] = $image;


// Get/create another image...
$image = array(
    'id' => 456,
    'description' => 'another kitty',
    // ... other fields here
);

// ... put it into the list (skip the helper variable $imageId)
$listImages[$image['id']] = $image;
```

This is how the output of `print_r($listImages)` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [123] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [description] => Nice kitty
            [medium] => http://www.blah.com/12345
            [full] => http://www.blah.com/67890
        )

    [456] => Array
        (
            [id] => 456
            [description] => another kitty
        )

)
```