# Push a full array rather than just an individual element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called `$this_image` created in a loop. At the end of the loop, I wish to add the array to a larger array.

`$this_image` looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [2161]=>
  array(3) {
    ["description"]=>
    string(10) "Description goes here"
    ["medium"]=>
    string(102) "http://localhost/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363-300x300.jpg"
    ["full"]=>
    string(94) "http://localhost/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363.jpg"
  }
}
```

I now wish to add this array to my more global array, `$all_images`. The result would be something like this:

`$all_images =`

```
array(2) {
      [2161]=>
      array(3) {
        ["description"]=>
        string(10) "Description goes here"
        ["medium"]=>
        string(102) "http://localhost/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363-300x300.jpg"
        ["full"]=>
        string(94) "http://localhost/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363.jpg"
      }
      [2162]=>
      array(3) {
        ["description"]=>
        string(10) "Another description goes here"
        ["medium"]=>
        string(102) "http://localhost/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363-300x300.jpg"
        ["full"]=>
        string(94) "http://localhost/new/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363.jpg"
      }
      ...
    }
```

How do I do this? I have tried using `array_push` but I find that I cannot push an array, only a  single string/int etc How do I add a new array to an existing one?

Previous question asked demonstrated how to initialise the new array with a number of element items, not how to push the array into an existing one.

Comment: `$all_images[] = $this_image;` ?!

Comment: @Rizier123 will that work pre PHP 5.4?

Comment: @SunilPachlangia I have provided examples, but I don't have any code... I'm asking how to do this.

Comment: @Rizier123 as per the documentation square brackets are to be used on 5.4+ only http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Rizier123, that will create a new element consisting of the array rather than merging the array with new elements at the same level as old elements.

Comment: @Francesca To define an array, but to add a new array element it works fine!

Comment: Has been working since forever in PHP... `array_push` should also do just fine as well. It's entirely unclear why it's not.

Comment: @Francesca, you are getting confused between `$arr[] = 'foo';` which has worked forever and `$arr = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];` which is new in 5.4.

Comment: Is your problem that you're trying to preserve the numeric keys (`2161` and `2162`) in both arrays?! If so, please spell that out.

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks I was just checking as I wasn't sure if it would not work on servers without 5.4

Comment: @Rizier123 Your example does not preserve the ID as specified in the OP, it inputs the array under `[0]`,`[1]` etc. As I specified, I wish the current `ID` to be the top level key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push array into an array using array\_push](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892799/push-array-into-an-array-using-array-push)

Comment: @Rizier123 here is an example of the output with your code. It does not match the output requested in the OP http://pastebin.com/1tgHsBDW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_merge`. Try with -

```
$all_images = array_merge($all_images, $this_image);
```

Or Rizier123 solution(`$all_images[] = $this_image;`) will also work.

Or you can do this also -

```
$all_images += $this_image; // will preserve the keys on top level also
```

Comment: Why not just: `$all_images[] = $this_image;` ?

Comment: This code loses the ID data and replaces it with 0,1 etc

Comment: @Francesca if want to preserve the ids then Rizier123 will work.

Comment: I think the array union operator `+` is indeed what is needed here.

Comment: But i am not sure which versions supports `+`.

Comment: PHP versions? That's been there since pretty much forever as well.

Comment: @sgtBOSE the option Rizier123 gave does not use the `[ID]` for the top-level key as specified in the OP. Please see the output here: http://pastebin.com/1tgHsBDW

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to demonstrate :

```
<?php

$a = array(1=>array('a','b'));
$b = array(2=>array('c','d'));

array_push($a, $b);

print_r($a);
?>
```

~                                                                                                                                                                                          `